# The difference between '납부할 금액' vs '납부해야 할 금액'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

So what is the difference between '납부할 금액' vs '납부해야 할 금액' in the following sentence and in general:

'10월 납부하실 금액 안내드립니다'

The sentence can be translated as '(we are) informing the amount to be paid in October'

why not '납부해야 하실 금액'?

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

납부해야 하실 금액 has stronger connotation that you are "required to" pay, which may seem impolite to some Koreans. But, to be honest, both work just fine.